# Prevent Facebook from hijacking GoodReads login on Safari desktop (Monterey)

Tags: macos, safari, login, facebook

When I visit https://www.goodreads.com (MacBook Pro 13" M1) and click on "Sign Up with Email", it takes me to the sign up page (https://www.goodreads.com/user/sign_up?email_signup=true). Unfortunately, before I can even begin to sign up, Facebook hijacks the page and tries to log me in.

I can easily use Firefox to prevent this from happening.

Although, I'm just curious (it seems like a fun problem to solve) as to how I can prevent Safari from allowing Facebook from hijacking the sign up process.

I have "Prevent cross-site tracking" ticked on the Privacy settings but that's not doing anything.

I used the web inspector (I'm not advanced in development, just HTML, CSS, and a little JS) and noticed something. It seems `oauth` could be the culprit, but that's just my limited knowledge talking.

Where do I go from here?

Comment: Does removing related cookies help?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Instead of accepting Facebook as a login (and having the ability to choose privacy settings), it takes me to a Facebook login page.

Comment: Does using a private Safari window when visiting https://www.goodreads.com solve the issue?